# Match sub-string within a string with tolerance of 1 character mismatch

Tags: c, string

I was going through some Amazon interview questions on CareerCup.com, and I came across this interesting question which I haven't been able to figure out how to do. I have been thinking on this since 2 days. Either I am taking a way off approach, or its a genuinely hard function to write.

**Question is as follows:**

Write a function in C that can find if a string is a sub-string of another. Note that a mismatch of one character
should be ignored.

```
A mismatch can be an extra character: ’dog’ matches ‘xxxdoogyyyy’  
A mismatch can be a missing character: ’dog’ matches ‘xxxdgyyyy’ 
A mismatch can be a different character: ’dog’ matches ‘xxxdigyyyy’
```

The return value wasn't mentioned in the question, so I assume the signature of the function can be something like this:

```
char * MatchWithTolerance(const char * str, const char * substr);
```

If there is a match with the given rules, return the pointer to the beginning of matched substring within the string. Else return null.

**Bonus**

If someone can also figure out a generic way of making the tolerance to n instead of 1, then that would be just brilliant.
In that case the signature would be:

```
char * MatchWithTolerance(const char * str, const char * substr, unsigned int tolerance = 1);
```

Comment: does `dog` also match `xxxdogyyy`?

Comment: (removed a set of comments that were unrelated to the question)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to work, let me know if you find any errors and I'll try to fix them:

```
int findHelper(const char *str, const char *substr, int mustMatch = 0)
{
    if ( *substr == '\0' )
        return 1;

    if ( *str == '\0' )
        return 0;

    if ( *str == *substr )
        return findHelper(str + 1, substr + 1, mustMatch);
    else
    {
        if ( mustMatch )
            return 0;

        if ( *(str + 1) == *substr )
            return findHelper(str + 1, substr, 1);
        else if ( *str == *(substr + 1) )
            return findHelper(str, substr + 1, 1);
        else if ( *(str + 1) == *(substr + 1) )
            return findHelper(str + 1, substr + 1, 1);
        else if ( *(substr + 1) == '\0' )
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}

int find(const char *str, const char *substr)
{
    int ok = 0;
    while ( *str != '\0' )
        ok |= findHelper(str++, substr, 0);

    return ok;
}


int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", find("xxxdoogyyyy", "dog"));
    printf("%d\n", find("xxxdgyyyy", "dog"));
    printf("%d\n", find("xxxdigyyyy", "dog"));
}
```

Basically, I make sure only one character can differ, and run the function that does this for every suffix of the haystack.

Comment: +1!! That works brilliantly. I am sure we can make this return pointer to the beginning of the matched string. And This can be made generic too. Thanks a lot!  If I come across any unmatching scenarios, I will reply back.

Comment: @IVlad Some Comments on each of the if else statements would help us understanding it easily. Pls consider doing it.

Answer (score 4):

This is related to a classical problem of IT, referred to as [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).
See [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance) for a bunch of implementations in different languages.

Comment: +1 for not writing code that's clearly going to be plagiarized and submit as his own.

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with the levenshtein distance as far as I can see. This asks for substring matching where 1 character is allowed not to match. How do you propose we use the levenshtein distance for this?

Comment: I should have been a little clearer. The Levenshtein implementations do not solve the original problem. But, looking at the algorithm you'll realize that only a slight change is needed to achieve fuzzy substring matching. Again, the internets has an implementation ready: http://ginstrom.com/scribbles/2007/12/01/fuzzy-substring-matching-with-levenshtein-distance-in-python/

Comment: @Stefan Why are you picking on me in every damn comment? I am not submitting this code anywhere! You didn't even read my question properly. I wrote, that I was going through interview questions and found this interesting. And I tried to solve it, but failed somehow. Why do you think that I am planning to plagiarize this? This means you don't even understand how interviews in real worls take place. No company would ask you to write that big a function on phone. They will only ask you to write such a code on face-2-face interview, where you clearly cannot copy-paste from Stack Overflow.

Comment: @bits: There are such thing as automated source code submissions, or email-based code submissions.

Comment: for those looking at the ginstrom.scribble example, one optimization can be to generate columns as you go rather than rows.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 How can we modify it for the case when mismatch can only be different character and not extra or missing characters ?

Answer (score 2):

This is slightly different than the earlier solution, but I was intrigued by the problem and wanted to give it a shot.  Obviously optimize if desired, I just wanted a solution.

```
char *match(char *str, char *substr, int tolerance)
{
  if (! *substr) return str;
  if (! *str) return NULL;

  while (*str)
  {
    char *str_p;
    char *substr_p;
    char *matches_missing;
    char *matches_mismatched;

    str_p = str;
    substr_p = substr;

    while (*str_p && *substr_p && *str_p == *substr_p)
    {
      str_p++;
      substr_p++;
    }
    if (! *substr_p) return str;
    if (! tolerance)
    {
      str++;
      continue;
    }

    if (strlen(substr_p) <= tolerance) return str;

    /* missed due to a missing letter */
    matches_missing = match(str_p, substr_p + 1, tolerance - 1);
    if (matches_missing == str_p) return str;

    /* missed due to a mismatch of letters */
    matches_mismatched = match(str_p + 1, substr_p + 1, tolerance - 1);
    if (matches_mismatched == str_p + 1) return str;

    str++;
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried out your solution yet, but Non-recursive approach is supposedly very difficult. +1 for Attempting.

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem to do this efficiently?

The naive solution is to loop over every substring of size `substr` in `str`, from left to right, and return true if the current substring if only one of the characters is different in a comparison.

Let n = size of str
Let m = size of substr

There are `O(n)` substrings in str, and the matching step takes time `O(m)`. Ergo, the naive solution runs in time
`O(n*m)`

Comment: I guess, efficiency wouldn't be the primary thing they are testing in the question. Still I would say, lets try to do it in O(n*m).

Comment: -1 This approach is not even close to the actual solution posted by IVlad.

Answer (score 0):

### With arbitary no. of tolerance levels.

Worked for all the test cases I could think of. Loosely based on |/|ad's solution.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

report (int x, char* str, char* sstr, int[] t) {
    if ( x )
        printf( "%s is a substring of %s for a tolerance[%d]\n",sstr,str[i],t[i] );
    else
        printf ( "%s is NOT a substring of %s for a tolerance[%d]\n",sstr,str[i],t[i] );
}

int find_with_tolerance (char *str, char *sstr, int tol) {

    if ( (*sstr) == '\0' ) //end of substring, and match
        return 1;

    if ( (*str) == '\0' ) //end of string
        if ( tol >= strlen(sstr) ) //but tol saves the day
            return 1;
        else    //there's nothing even the poor tol can do
            return 0;

    if ( *sstr == *str ) { //current char match, smooth
        return find_with_tolerance ( str+1, sstr+1, tol );
    } else {
        if ( tol <= 0 ) //that's it. no more patience
            return 0;
        for(int i=1; i<=tol; i++) {
            if ( *(str+i) == *sstr ) //insertioan of a foreign character
                return find_with_tolerance ( str+i+1, sstr+1, tol-i );
            if ( *str == *(sstr+i) ) //deal with dletion
                return find_with_tolerance ( str+1, sstr+i+1, tol-i );
            if ( *(str+i) == *(sstr+i)  ) //deal with riplacement
                return find_with_tolerance ( str+i+1, sstr+i+1, tol-i );
            if ( *(sstr+i) == '\0' ) //substr ends, thanks to tol & this loop
                return 1;
        }
        return 0; //when all fails
    }
}

int find (char *str, char *sstr, int tol ) {
    int w = 0;
    while (*str!='\0')
        w |= find_with_tolerance ( str++, sstr, tol );
    return (w) ? 1 : 0;
}

int main() {
    const int n=3; //no of test cases
    char *sstr = "dog"; //the substr
    char *str[n] = { "doox", //those cases
                    "xxxxxd",
                    "xxdogxx" };
    int t[] = {1,1,0}; //tolerance levels for those cases
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        report( find ( *(str+i), sstr, t[i] ), *(str+i), sstr, t[i] );
    }
    return 0;
}
```